# save times clicked on hyperlink/linkbutton

Tags: asp.net, html, c#-4.0

I am going to have a listview with links that get binded from the database.  I am wanting to track when that link gets clicked on.  This will be so i can tell what links are clicked on the most.  I tried doing this with a linkbutton, but ran into the problem where the color does not change when it is visited.  I doubt i can do it with a hyperlink since the hyperlink does not hit the server.  Any suggestions on how to do this.

This is how i did the linkbuttons

```
<asp:ListView ID="lstvTopTen" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>

        <tr>
            <td width="100%">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnUrlLink" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NewsTitle") %>' 
                    CommandArgument='<%# Bind("NewsUrl") %>' onclick="lbtnUrlLink_Click" 
                    OnDataBinding="lbtnUrlLink_DataBinding" CssClass="newslink" />
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NewsDescriptionDisplay") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

here is my css

```
    .newslink 
{
    display:block;
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:1.2em;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;
}

.newslink:visited
{
    color: Red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how i ended up doing it.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("NewsUrl") %>' Target="_blank"
                    onclick="countClick(this.href);" CssClass="newslink" Text='<%# Bind("NewsTitle") %>' />



<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function countClick(name) {

        PageMethods.CountClick(name);

    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you create a LinkButton, the rendered code will have have a **javascript function call** instead of a URL to another page. So the browser will not store these into its history. Also the **:visited** pseudo class will not work in this case, since it only works for **URLs** not javascript function calls!

To get around this, you might have to create a new javascript function to capture when the user has clicked on the link, and then change the style.

For example:

```
<script>
function ChangeLinkColour()
{
    document.getElementById('myLink').style.color = "Black";
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Your LinkButton will look like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="myLink" runat="server" Text="Click me" OnClientClick="return ChangeLinkColour();" CssClass="a"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Would it be more viable to have a hyperlink with a javascript code to add one to the database for clicks?  It would be nice to have the link retain the click on color.  If i do this javascript method it won't retain it.

Comment: Well if you must keep the visited colour, then you could change that linkbutton to a hyperlink. Then in the href, add a querystring value to the end. So on your pageload check for that querystring value and increment the times that link was clicked in the database. As you have noticed this might not give you the exact number of times clicked though...

Answer (score -1):

Look at the answer in this post.  You are pretty close.

```
.newslink a:visited 
{

}
```

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317106/applying-css-to-my-asp-net-linkbutton)

Comment: I can get hover to work but i can't get visited or active.  hover only works when doing ".newslink:hover"  The others don't work any way i do it.